# What is the most efficient way to a multiple variable in dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

this my code, i'm looking, is other way to code this in most efficient way?
  i have multiple variables and inserted to the dictionary.
  please feel to suggest and other options like array and etc will do.

```
def momentEndSpan(span_type,max_combo,length):
    if "simply supported" == span_type:
        q = max_combo
        force = {}
        RA = {"PA" : q*length/2}
        RB = {"PB" : q*length/2}
        RA_moment = {"MA" : 0}
        R_mid_moment = {"Mmid": (q*math.pow(length,2))/8 }
        RB_moment = { "MB" : 0}
        force.update(RA)
        force.update(RB)
        force.update(RA_moment)
        force.update(R_mid_moment)
        force.update(RB_moment)
        return force
    elif "one end continuous" == span_type:
        q = max_combo
        x = (3/8)*length
        force = {}
        RA = {"Phinge" : 3*q*length/8}
        RB = {"Pfixed" : 5*q*length/8}
        RA_moment = {"Mhinge" : 0}
        R_mid_moment = {"Mmid": (q*math.pow(length,2))*(9/128) }
        RB_moment = { "MB" : -1*(q*math.pow(length,2))/8 }
        force.update(RA)
        force.update(RB)
        force.update(RA_moment)
        force.update(R_mid_moment)
        force.update(RB_moment)
        return force
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "More Pythonic" way is to create one dictionary and update once.

```
q = max_combo
force = {} 

if "simply supported" == span_type:
    new = {"PA" : q*length/2,
           "PB" : q*length/2,
           "MA" : 0, "Mmid": (q*math.pow(length,2))/8,
           "MB" : 0}

elif "one end continuous" == span_type:
        x = (3/8)*length
        new = {"Phinge" : 3*q*length/8,
               "Pfixed" : 5*q*length/8,
               "Mhinge" : 0,
               "Mmid": (q*math.pow(length,2))*(9/128),
               "MB" : -1*(q*math.pow(length,2))/8 }

force.update(new)
```

Also, note that if the `force` dictionary doesn't contain any previously defined items you can simply return the `new` and/or just continue to update the `new` in your next operations if there are any. Or just use name `force` instead of `new`.

```
q = max_combo

if "simply supported" == span_type:
    force = {...}

elif "one end continuous" == span_type:
        x = (3/8)*length
        force = {...}
```

Comment: Why the `force.update()` call? Just do `force = {...}` in either branch.